# Pass and receive data in Vaadin 8

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin8

I have a view:

```
@SpringUI(path="order")
@Title("order")
public class OrderGUI extends UI{
```

and I would pass parameter to other:

```
@SpringUI(path="orderNumber")
@Title("Order number")
public class GetOrderNumber extends UI {
```

I tried to send parameter(orderNumber) by:

```
getUI().getPage().setUriFragment(orderNumber);
getUI().getPage().setLocation("orderNumber");
```

then it goes to `/orderNumber` but when tried to catch it by:

```
String fragment = getPage().getUriFragment();
```

but

```
System.out.println("Fragment: " + fragment);
```

says that `Fragment: null`

How to send parameter from one Vaadin view to another?

@Edit
It is close to work. I have changed my View to:

```
@SpringView(name = "GetOrderNumber")
@Title("Order number")
public class GetOrderNumber extends VerticalLayout implements View {
```

and in @SpringUI made `getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo("GetOrderNumber/" + orderNumber);`

it actually still throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Trying to navigate to an unknown state '' and an error view provider not present` but it works. I mean all the time when I go to localhost:8080/order the

```
@SpringUI(path="order")
public class OrderGUI extends UI {
```

throws an error but then works as expected - go to view and pass parameter right. I have no idea why `navigator = new Navigator(this, this);` cause an error

Answer (score 2):

@SpringUI annotation defines always just the name of the view, it is not the place where you give the URI parameter, the correct place is the navigateTo(..) method, e.g.:

```
getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo("myview/someparameter");
```

There is more information about Vaadin and Spring add-on here

https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-spring.html

Comment: First shot - changed to         `getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo("orderNumber/" + orderNumber);`
and got `java.lang.NullPointerException: null`

Comment: Not even strange if I don't have object of Navigator class

Comment: Yes, you need to setup navigator first. Usually you do it in in main UI class in small apps or mainview/layout/whatever class in bigger apps. The documentation of Navigator is here:

https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-navigator.html

Comment: Also note that views should be annotated with `@SpringView` and extend the `com.vaadin.navigator.View` interface, whereas the example  code here is using the `@SpringUI` annotation and extends the `com.vaadin.ui.UI` class. There should typically only be one `UI` class per application, but multiple `View` classes.

Comment: I followed documentation linked by @TatuLund and as far as I add `navigator = new Navigator(this, this);
        navigator.addView("", new GetOrderNumber());`
My site is blank. Why is that?
@Edit actually `navigator.addView("", new GetOrderNumber());` makes my site blank

Comment: @Michu93 If you want  to pass order number to the view as the parameter, you should not give it in addView(..) method. Instead you should do it this way

navigator.addView("myview");
navigator.navigateTo("myview/"+GetOrderNumber());

Comment: @Michu93 Sorry, I thought GetOrderNumber() is getter for your parameter, but then I noticed that it is a view. You should register your view with this syntax: 
navigator.addView("myview", GetOrderNumber.class);
And when you navigate to "myview" and pass parameter to it you do it with navigator.navigateTo("myview/"+orderNumber);

Comment: GetOrderNumber is so dumb name for a class.
When I add `navigator = new Navigator(this, this);
        navigator.addView("myview", GetOrderNumber.class);` it immediately throw `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Trying to navigate to an unknown state '' and an error view provider not present
`

Comment: Actually `navigator = new Navigator(this, this);` throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Have you added navigator.navigateTo("myview"); call? If you do not have a view with name "" registered, your will get exception. So then you need to add navigation to default view.